# Correlated Random Walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

If there was a random walk in three dimensions where the angle between any to two connected segments were fixed (rotation allowed around this angle). What would be the best way to show that the expected displacement of this walk away from the origin is zero?

If this helps I know that if you are given a prior step $\vec{r}_n$, then the expectation value for the next step is $\langle \vec{r}_{n+1}\rangle = \vec{r}_n\cos{\theta}$, where $\theta$ is the angle between to edges since the perpendicular portion of the $\vec{r}_{n+1}$ vector has an equal probability of going in any direction.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the setup correctly, it is symmetric under inversion, i.e. the random walk is equally likely to start off in a given direction or the opposite direction, and the angle constraints for subsequent steps also respect this invariance. Then the expected displacement is zero by symmetry.